# No action in params in github webhook payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, parameters, webhooks

I am sending to an organization webhook the pull_request payload as described here : https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

But while in my script i can get any parameter from the payload using

```
params[:foo][:bar]
```

i cannot get the first param which is the action using

```
params[:action]
```

it's not giving anything

i am reading here that it should be there under params[:action] : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/action_controller_overview.html

I don't know what i am doing wrong the webhook is sending the pull_request even as expected but the param is just not there, when i check the dump is starts with the pr number not the action.